# How to convert a JavaScript object to a server object?

Tags: javascript

Into an server object like this:

Does anyone know how to turn a Javascript object like this:

8: Object
$$hashKey: "object:212"
differentLayout: false
index: 8
panoCount: 6
panoDataRotate: 0
roomModelId: "56aebc872e958a0051c06487"
type: "VRoom"
x: 210
y: 244
**proto**: Object

Into a server object like this?

```
0: s
_allPreviousSaves: t.exports
_changing: false
_escapedAttributes: Object
_existed: true
_hasData: true
_hashedJSON: Object
_opSetQueue: Array[1]
_pending: Object
_previousAttributes: Object
_saving: NaN
_serverData: Object
_silent: Object
attributes: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c3"
createdAt: Mon Feb 01 2016 10:02:02 GMT+0800 (台北標準時間)
id: "56aebc9a128fe10051a7e8f8"
updatedAt: Mon Feb 01 2016 18:20:29 GMT+0800 (台北標準時間)
__proto__: t
```

*Note:* Right now I know to do the opposite. `s.toJSON()` will turn the server object in to a Javascript object.

**EDIT**:

This is how I create the server object:

```
AV.Object.extend('PanoramaData')
var panodata = new Panodata();
```

Comment: What do you refer to by the term "server object"?

Comment: you have Create your own Parser in server side , so
create method `createPanodataFromJson(jsonClientSide){
   //loop through your data and create fieldd by field
}` a the end rerturn the generated `Panodata`

Comment: @arkascha Not sure if that's the right word. But in my console it shows as `s` instead of `Object`. And it has the properties that I pasted.

Comment: what's your server side programing language? If it's not a dynamic language, I think you should create your own class refer to the javascript object , and create a constructor to serialize and deserialize the object. It belong to the datatype you use to transmit the data from client to server, It may be the string type or binary type. usually, you need to convert a json string to the server class

Comment: @Jack The server code is JavaScript, it's a bit like Parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify()` to serialize your object and send it to the server.

You should read it from the server and use a function which can decode this string data to a server object (like `json_decode()` in PHP) to create an intermediate object. This depends on the server technology you use.

Pass this object to the conversion routine to do the changes you need.

Comment: Why PHP? I don't see the PHP tag on this Q&A :\

Comment: Yeah, `s.toJSON()` does not look like PHP. I'm guessing ASP or C#.